# Android Wear + Wearable ChannelApi openChannel not opening with remote node?

Tags: android, wear-os

When opening a channel via a **local node**:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(googleApiClient)
```

... the onChannelOpened Listener **successfully** fires.

However, when opening a channel via a **remote node**:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient)
```

... the onChannelOpened Listener **never** fires and subsequently can never share files over this channel.

I know openChannel is required for both devices, but the channel listeners are only firing on the device that opened it locally...  How does the remote device send or receive files as well if it doesn't know it's connected? Here's breakdown between the two devices

**Wearable :**

1. save local file - successful
2. .openChannel with local (wearable) node - successful
3. .sendFile to channel - successful

**Handle Held :**

1. .openChannel with remote (wearable) node - fail
2. .receiveFile from channel - fail
3. display file - fail

Comment: It'd be useful to post something about how the calls fail. What's the status code you get back from openChannel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Toubleshooting**

Here are a few things to check:

- Are you getting message events or data item updates? If you call [`Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html#sendMessage(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20byte[])), do you get `onMessageReceived` on the other device? If not, there could be something wrong with how [`WearableListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) is set up on the other node, or with the way your app is packaged (e.g your microapp and app are in different packages, or are signed with different keys).
- Are you running the latest version of the [Android Wear app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app)? The Channel API was added recently, and it may be that your watch still hasn't received the update to support it. Version 1.1.1.1889093 should be fine.

**How to use the Channel API**

By the way, it sounds like you can simplify your use of channels. There's no need to open channels both to the local and to the remote node. The way you'd normally use the API is:

1. Decide whether you want to start the channel from the watch or from the phone. In this case, it sounds like you're starting it from the watch.
2. In the watch app, call [`Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi.html#openChannel(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), pointing at the phone app. This method returns a `PendingResult<OpenChannelResult>`. When it completes successfully, you'll get a [`Channel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Channel.html) object. This is the watch's side of the channel, and you can use it to send a file.
3. In the phone app, include a `WearableListenerService`, which should get an `onChannelOpened` event. That method will be passed a `Channel` object, which is the phone's side of the channel. You can call `receiveFile` on that object.

So as you can see, you should only have one call to `openChannel`: to the remote node.

Comment: While I fixed this awhile ago (using the messaging api as an example, very similar usages) your comment was spot on. Thanks.

Comment: Nimrod Gileadi said that it could be a problem when "your microapp and app are in different packages, or are signed with different keys". For my development purposes it was better to have two separated apps for smartwatch and smartphone. Is it still somehow possible that these two apps can communicate with each other over the Message or Channel API or do I need to bind the smartwatch apk to the smartphone apk to realize that?

Comment: I figured it out by myself. You can change the ``applicationId`` in build.gradle (Module: app). Then the separated smartwatch app is able to communicate with all apps with the same applicationId (package name).