# Android Wear + Wearable ChannelApi + How to open connection to cloud node (WIFI)?

Tags: android, wear-os

The connection via bluetooth using the new Channel API is working like it should, but if I now switch to the cloud node (WIFI mode) the channel can't be opened. The result is always null and running into a timeout.

```
ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult result = Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel(googleApiClient, "cloud", Constants.COPY_FILE_VIA_CHANNEL_PATH).await();
```

Is this the right way to establish a WIFI connection between nodes and is there somewhere an example how to implement this?

### update:

on watch: 
(afterwards send nodeID to phone via message. I used this approach after also seeing the problems from this thread [Android Wear + Wearable ChannelApi openChannel not opening with remote node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018709/android-wear-wearable-channelapi-openchannel-not-opening-with-remote-node/30235054#30235054))

on watch: (Send retrieved localNodeID to phone)

```
NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult localNodeResult = Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(googleApiClient).await();
```

on phone:

```
ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult result = Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel(googleApiClient, localNodeId, Constants.COPY_FILE_VIA_CHANNEL_PATH).await();

Channel.GetOutputStreamResult getOutputStreamResult = channel.getOutputStream(googleApiClient).await();

OutputStream outputStream = getOutputStreamResult.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(byteChunk);
            outputStream.close();
```

on watch:

```
 @Override
public void onChannelOpened(Channel channel) {
    if (channel.getPath()
               .equals(Constants.COPY_FILE_VIA_CHANNEL_PATH)) {
        new SaveDataFromChannelTask(channel).execute();
    }
}

protected class SaveDataFromChannelTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final Channel channel;

    public SaveDataFromChannelTask(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Channel.GetInputStreamResult getInputStreamResult = channel.getInputStream(googleApiClient)
                                                                   .await();
        InputStream inputStream = getInputStreamResult.getInputStream();
        saveFileToDisk(inputStream);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is currently the implementation inside the "Wear Media" app, which is using the Channel API. Inside the settings the chunksize can be modified to any byte value between 1000 and 9999999, but during transfer and activated bluetooth and WIFI always the bluetooth connection is used.

Answer (score 0):

`"cloud"` is not a valid node id - you need to use a node id of a device such as a phone or Android Wear device. The devices will automatically switch from bluetooth to wifi based on the underlying connection - there is nothing you need to do. You can use the [CapabilityApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi), similar to the [sending messages training](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html), to correctly determine the node id to open a channel with.

Comment: I thought this as well and used this for the communication, but unfortunately this didn't work automatically. Before transferring files from phone to watch I'm requesting the localnode-id from the watch and then I'm opening a channel including a stream. But always only the bluetooth connection is used, although a WIFI connection is established.

Comment: "This didn't work" is not enough information to debug your problem. Add your code using an actual receiving node and the code on the other end.

Comment: Sorry, the enter key was faster than I thought ;)

Comment: Added now  a more detailed description of the problem. Hopefully you can see an issue inside the implementation.

Comment: The answer on the question you linked looks like the answer for your question as well: you need to open a channel with the other device's nodeId: your phone code shows `localNodeId` - not the watch's ID.

Comment: hm, actually I'm doing this by retrieving the localNodeId inside the watch app and sending it back to the phone per MessageAPI. Otherwise if I would use the localNodeID from the phone the transfer wouldn't work at all. I think the localNodeID's inside the wearable network are unique, so the method I'm using or the way via the Capability Api should deliver the same ID, right?

Comment: Yes, it would just be a lot easier to understand :)

Comment: This could be, but it was created before I knew the Capability API ;) Nevertheless the automatic switching from BT to WIFI isn't working and I'll try to figure out why. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: As I said in my original answer: the devices will automatically switch between bluetooth and wifi - you have no control over the protocol used.

Comment: Finally the switch to WIFI is working as a result of the update from Google Play Services to 7.5.71 :) But it's strange, the transfer rate is 3-4 times slower than with bluetooth :D